# Getting a notice for "Trying to access array of type bool" despite the same function working both above and below the troublesome query

Tags: php, sql, web

So, I am trying to work on some PHP for classes, but am running into an issue with the above notice.
The code is:

```
    <select name="RAM" id="RAM" style="grid-column: 2/ span 3; grid-row:8;">
        <?php foreach ($RAM as $row): ?>    
        <option><?=$row["name"]?></option>  
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </select>
    <label style="grid-column:5; grid-row:8">
        <?php showPrice($_POST["RAM"])?>
        </label>

    <select name="Storage" id="Storage" style="grid-column: 2/ span 3; grid-row:9;">
        <?php foreach ($STORAGE as $row): ?>    
        <option><?=$row["name"]?></option>  
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </select>
        <label style="grid-column:5; grid-row:9">
            <?php showPrice($_POST["Storage"])?>
        </label>
```

The errant section is the one labeled "RAM", which produces the error notice. 
I've tried echoing the $_POST to see if it gets the name of the selected item correctly.
I've used the name within the SQL database to see if something was wrong with the names between the two.

But both of those do return the proper value I need, and the "Storage" section above does work as intended, so I can't quite tell what's causing it.

Comment: What does the `RAM` column contain?

Comment: In the select it contains the name as a textstring and in the database there is a price associated with it

There is an sql query that "SELECTS price FROM component WHERE name=$name" where $name is the $_POST value

Comment: What does the function `showPrice()` do? Add the function to your question.